Why should we not round off in the middle of calculations?
Does rounding off in the middle of a calculation end up giving you wrong answers at the end of calculations?
Why should we not round off in the middle of calculations?

This question is similar to: Do you round uncertainties in intermediate calculations?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Another possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63328/

You should ideally never round off a number. Rounding means that you introduce an error. If you introduce an error early on, then it risks multiplying and accumulating through your calculations, making the final error even larger. If you for example add the three numbers $1.3$, $2.3$, and $3.3$, then the true sum without any error is $6.9$. You could now round off to $7$, making it slightly incorrect but easier to read. The error is only $0.1$. Rounding off before adding would result in $1+2+3=6$; much worse and much farther from the correct value with an error of $0.9$.

@Steeven: But if you round the intermediate results to the nearest integer, you're essentially saying that the intermediate results are only accurate within a margin of error of 0.5. If this applies to all three of them, then the margin of error for the end result is $\sqrt{0.5^2+0.5^2+0.5^2}\approx 0.9$. So the error introduced by rounding is within (or extremely close to) the margin of error we have to assume either way.
